# Software (online or desktop) that allows me to monitor many (like many) email inboxes (that I can import)

Tags: email, email-client

Im looking for some type of software that helps me to monitor many (like many) email inboxes.

I have thousands of email inboxes that I monitor, I would like some kind of software where I can import all the settings from a .csv file (email address, IMAP server, password and so on) and then just look at "what's in there".

Think of it as Outlook Desktop with "import email accounts" capabilities (but can ofc be SAAS aswell).

Any ideas?